# disable/enable click event Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have a CheckBox with id "CB" and a Button with id "BT" . I want to validate  :

1. if CB checked , event Click of BT is Enable
2. If CB UnChecked, event Click of BT is Disable

so how the right script if inner this the Jquery ?

```
    var CB = $("#CB");
    var inital_CB  = CB .is(":checked");

    var BT= $("#BT").attr("disabled", !inital_CB);

    CB .click(function() {
        BT.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
```

Comment: What's your question? The code above should work.. Here is a simplified version - http://jsfiddle.net/xbf5ud7u/

Comment: code above just add/remove attribut HTML "Disable" in BT.
i want to add code too where event "CLICK" of BT is disable or enable if condition CB checked or not ... but i dont know how to this

Comment: enable = BT can to click , disable = BT Can not to click

Answer (score 0):

If all your wanting to do is to trigger some code depending on if the checkbox is selected or not, here you go:

```
var theButton = document.getElementById("Button1");
var theCheckBox = document.getElementById("Checkbox1");
theButton.onclick = function () {
    if (theCheckBox.checked) {
        //Code that executes when checkbox is selected
    }
    else {
        //Code that executes when checkbox is not selected
    }
}
```